# Android - How to use the PhoneGap Share plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to use the PhoneGap Share plugin which is supposed to bring up the native Android "Share" window which allows the user to pick which application to share to.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share

I have a hyperlink which calls the following code (provided on github).

```
window.plugins.share.show({
    subject: 'I like turtles',
    text: 'http://www.mndaily.com'
},

function () {}, // Success function
function () {
    alert('Share failed')
} // Failure function);
```

When trying to debug the app on my phone, I get the following error:

Cannot call method 'show' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have faced the same problem today. I made it work using the following code instead of the window.plugins thing:

```
var share = new Share();
share.show({
    subject: 'I like turtles',
    text: 'http://www.mndaily.com'},
    function() {}, // Success function
    function() {alert('Share failed')} // Failure function

);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can do...

- Add to `plugins.xml`:

  ```
  <plugin name="Share" value="com.schaul.plugins.share.Share"/ >
  ```
- Save `share.js` to `\assets\www\`
- From `index.html`, call

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="share.js" ></script>
  ```
- Add `Share.java` to `\src\com.schaul.plugins.share`
  that is: src\com\schaul\plugins\share\Share.java
- In `index.html`, call the following code after the phonegap.1.2.0.js and share.js files are loaded:

Call the code that Petroy mentioned...

```
var share = new Share();
share.show({
    subject: 'I like turtles',
    text: 'http://www.mndaily.com'},
    function() {}, // Success function
    function() {alert('Share failed')} // Failure function

);
```

Let us know it works...

Comment: a better explanation to utilize share plugin. But plugins.xml has changed to config.xml, hence one put the xml code inside config.xml -> <plugins> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use updated version for cordova 2.7 and above from

https://github.com/robincharummoottil/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that the object window.plugins does not have a "share property".

Check that you followed the [installation steps](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Share) of the share plugin, and that you added the loading of the share.js file in your index.html, something the installation steps omits to tell you.

Comment: I think I followed the steps properly. I added the Share.java file to /src/com.schaul.plugins.share, I have added the share.js to my /assets/www, and I have called this script from my index.html. Am I misunderstanding the step "Add Java code to project's build source?"  I am new to both Eclipse and Java, so I'm not certain what this means, and can't find clear answers anywhere.